# How can I access members of a JsonResult?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, jsonresult

For reasons, I am having to to try and check if the content of a JsonResult is simply "true" however I cannot find a way to access it. The object itself shows that the data is there in the object under "Value", however, typing ".Value" on the end of the object is invalid.

(I cannot simply refactor this so that I'm getting a regular string return instead of JsonResult as that would involve a lot of other code changes)

[image]

Comment: What is `IsNotExistingTacAd`? What does it return? Is it an MVC action perhaps? Please post code as text, not images.

Comment: you really _should_ refactor this. especially so it returns a _boolean_... (also: is the return type of `IsNotExistingCadAd` by any chance `Task<object>` or similar, and you need to _cast_ your result to `JsonResponse` first?)

Comment: Could you provide the implementation for `IsNotExistingTacAd`?

Just a suggestion, try doing a null check:

`if(result?.Value != "true")`

It could be that `IsNotExistingTacAdd` returns a nullable value, so you'll get a compilation error if you don't check it correctly.  Not best practice, but you could also use `dynamic`instead of `var`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can use this code

```
var result= await IsNot....;

if ( result.Value!=null && bool.TryParse(result.Value.ToString(), out var success))
    if ( success ) { };
```

but if you had in your action this code

```
return  new JsonResult (true);
```

you would not have to convert

```
var success = result.Value as bool?;

if ((success != null) && (bool) success) { };
```

Comment: Simplest fix was to cast so I did `var result = (JsonResult) await...` and the problem went away.